# CSS how to separate items and make it clean / spaced out

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to make a menu, there are 4 sections and each section has 6 menu items. I want the 4 sections to have their own corner, and I want each section to list the 6 items in 2 colums/3 rows.

I made classes that separate the sections and also seperates the menu items. This is what [my menu looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b878V.png)
and
[this is how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nP2Ta.png)

So what's the css code that would make it look like the one in the picture.

```jsx
const Food = () => {

    return (
        <div> <h2 class ="AppHead">Appetizers</h2>
        
        <div class = 'whole-menu'>

        <div class = "section">
            {data.appetizers.map((food) => {
                    return (

                        
                        <div class = "food-item">                        
                        {food.name}
                        <span>- </span>
                        {food.price}
                        <p> </p>
                        {food.description}
                        </div>
                        
                    )
            })} </div>


<div class = "section">
            {data.dishes.map((food) => {
                    return (

                        
                        <div class = "food-item">                        
                        {food.name}
                        <span>- </span>
                        {food.price}
                        <p> </p>
                        {food.description}
                        </div> 
                    )
                    
            })} </div>

<div class = "section">
                        {data.desserts.map((food) => {
                    return (

                        
                        <div class = "food-item">                        
                        {food.name}
                        <span>- </span>
                        {food.price}
                        <p> </p>
                        {food.description}
                        </div>
                    )
                    
            })} </div>


<div class = "section">
                        {data.drinks.map((food) => {
                    return (

                        
                        <div class = "food-item">                        
                        {food.name}
                        <span>- </span>
                        {food.price}
                        <p> </p>
                        {food.description}
                        </div>
                    )
                    
            })} </div>
        </div> </div>
    );
        };



export default Food;
```

Comment: Since this is a CSS question, please make it easy for us and add your HTML instead of JSX.

Comment: there's practically nothing in the index, I'm showing the jsx so you can have access to the class names

Comment: I mean the *rendered* HTML.

Comment: In the description I show my rendered html and what I want it to look like, there are 2 photos.

Comment: Not how it looks, but the HTML code itself. We don't know what `data` is, and we don't want to guess/compile your JSX ourselves. *Please* copy that HTML code and paste it here.